# Brief explanation of the return statement in the given javascript code

Tags: javascript, function, return-value

Can anybody give me the brief explanation of the  return statement in the given javascript code. 
Please you should see my fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/m6mxdt9u/

```
function isPrime(value) {
     if (!isPrime.answers)
         isPrime.answers = {};

     if (isPrime.answers[value] != null) {
         return isPrime.answers[value];
     }

     var prime = value != 1; // 1 can never be prime
     for (var i = 2; i < value; i++) {
         if (value % i == 0) {
             prime = false;
             break;
         }
     }
     return isPrime.answers[value] = prime;
 }

 assert(isPrime(5), "5 is prime!");
 assert(isPrime.answers[5], "The answer was cached!");

 function assert(value, desc) {
     var resultsList = document.getElementById("results");
     if (!resultsList) {
         resultsList = document.createElement('ul');
         document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(resultsList);
         resultsList.setAttribute('id', 'results');
     }
     var li = document.createElement("li");
     li.className = value ? "pass" : "fail";
     li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(desc));
     resultsList.appendChild(li);
 }
```

I struggled in this line :

```
 return isPrime.answers[value];
```

What will be the return value of the above code and where does it go?

Comment: All of the relevant code should be included in the question itself.

Comment: The return value is `isPrime.answers[value]` and it goes to the caller of the function. But that's not what you are really asking for, is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're asking about this particular part of the code:

```
 if (isPrime.answers[value] != null) {
     return isPrime.answers[value];
 }
```

Then it'll return whether `value` is prime or not, based on the cached value (value saved on the answers hash). It'll be the value returned by the `isPrime` function.

Comment: Actually there are two return statements one is in if condition another one is in function's return statement.So which one goes to the caller function?

Comment: The first one to be executed. If the if condition there is true, then it'll be that one, otherwise, the last return will be the one that gets executed. Remember that when a return statement is reached in JS, nothing else below it (inside the function) will be executed.